# twitter:image not visible for Vue.js application

Tags: vue.js, twitter, seo

I am having issues with the Twitter card of a Vue.js application. When I run the url through the [Twitter card validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator), all the checks pass but the image is not displayed.

I went through the troubleshoot guide from Twitter and applied the changes below to the image, but I could still not resolve the issue. https://twittercommunity.com/t/card-error-unable-to-render-or-no-image-read-this-first/62736

- Image ratio 2:1
- image size: 252 kb
- absolute path for url: https://speakher.jp/banner_twitter.png
- curl -v -A Twitterbot  returns status code 200

This is how I am defining the image in the `index.html` file of the project. The image is saved in the public folder.

```
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://speakher.jp/banner_twitter.png">
```

Do you have any pointers as to what might be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the Twitter Card Validator right now shows the correct image. Sometimes the card you're seeing is cached, so if you want to look at the latest version of the image, just add a parameter with a random name and (optionally) a random value.

For the link https://speakher.jp, for example, just adding a small random parameter will force Twitter to load the latest version of the image. This should load the same page since the parameter means nothing (normally).

```
https://speakher.jp?000000000001
```

You can also use this same method when posting your actual link to Twitter. This will ensure that the latest card preview is always used by Twitter.

I got this card from the validator. This seems to match the image in the link you provided.
[image: Card screenshot]

Comment: That's great, thank you so much! So what you did by validating the same url with a random parameter at the end cleared the cache?

Comment: @RossellaFerrandino Not really. It's essentially the same link (or at least they point to the same target, your `index.html` page), but Twitter doesn't see it that way since there was a change in query parameters. This causes Twitter to load the page as it appears live on the internet, instead of some sort of cache. It technically doesn't clear the cache (but Twitter automatically does that after some time), but it ensures that the latest page is parsed by the validator.